# Create a GitHub webhook for when a pull request is accepted & merged to master

Tags: git, github, pull-request, webhooks, github-enterprise

I have a webhook that currently fires on `push` to any branch. This triggers the webhook far too frequently. Ideally, the webhook would only fire when a pull request is **merged** into `master`. I don't see that as an option, though:

[image]

Is there a way to get additional webhook options or to customize the webhook somehow?

Comment: can you tell how you solved this issue? because i am facing same issue, i need to trigger the job only when the changes pushed to master branch.

Answer (score 52):

So, you can't customize the conditions of the trigger, but as LeGec mentions you can customize your code to only trigger when the Pull Request is merged.

To do that, make sure your script responds to the [PullRequestEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent). The conditions to test are:

- "action" is "**closed**"
- "merged" (inside of "pull_request") is **true**

This way your script can ignore all the pings it receives when any other activity occurs on the Pull Request (including closing without merging).

Answer (score 19):

I don't see any way to customize the conditions of the trigger.

I would suggest to rather write code on the receiving end to trigger your action only when you detect that the push fits your conditions, e.g :

- `payload.ref == "refs/head/master"`
- `payload.commits[0] matches the structure of a merged pull request` (<- this may require getting some extra info from the [commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/))